# node.js Query database using mongoose in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, socket.io

Right now,  I'm writing a small web application using node.js with my partner. In the application, we need to query some data from database using mongoose, then, send the data to the client.Trying to do this, I'm using the code below:

```
 io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var id = socket.id;
    socket.on('request', function (data) {

        mongoose.createConnection(dbConfig.url);
        var ClassX = require("./models/" + data.request);
        var class_query = ClassX.findOne({}, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("There is an error: "+ err);
                return handleError(err);
            }
            if (!result) {
                console.log("No result!");
            }
            io.sockets.to(id).emit("response", result);
        });

    });

});
```

**But it doesn't work.**

And when the code is running, the log file of the database show some information like below:

```
2017-02-23T15:40:48.426+0800 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:5015 #3 (3 connections now open)
2017-02-23T15:40:48.428+0800 I NETWORK  [conn3] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:5015 conn3: { driver: { name: "n
odejs", version: "2.2.24" }, os: { type: "Windows_NT", name: "win32", architecture: "x64", version: "10.0.14393" }, plat
form: "Node.js v6.9.5, LE, mongodb-core: 2.1.8" }
```

The information "[conn3] received client metadata ..." seems weird. And, from the experience of many attempts, I think **the callback function of ClassX.finOne()** has not been executed. And I totally don't know why.

Comment: I dont think you got your 'request' callback on socket.io fired

Comment: @AdamWolski could you explain a bit more? I don't quite understand what seems to go wrong.

Comment: It is also not a good idea to make a mongoose connection for every user that connects through sockets. Create the connection when starting up your app and re-use the connection to query the database.

Comment: It's clearly weird to create your connection here, moreover that's why it doesn't work because the connection will take some times to connect and you possibly try to query a database which is not yet connected.